Print floats of an array and respective quantity of each
I've been trying to code a program in C that, given a float array, determines how many of each number there are, and then, prints each number and their respective frequency. This is an exercise from my college (computer science course). In total, I must have spent like 3 hours trying to think about a solution and I just can't think. I'm certain this is trivial, though.
I couldn't develop anything that I thought would work. If i go to VS and try to code something to solve this, my mind freezes at the moment I would need to think how to represent the mechanism that makes the computer "know" if a number in a given position and its frequency were already accounted for before in the (int) frequency array.
(For everyone's comprehension, I modified the text above after posting it because I forgot about the word "array" and mistranslated to english. In portuguese (my native language), it is "vetor", so I assumed it was "vector", which is another existing english word. However, that one for sure doesn't seem be used as much as "array" to represent this in english programming discussions.)
#include <stdio.h>

#define VEC_LEN 8

int main(void)
{
    int vFreq[VEC_LEN] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 };
    float vNums[VEC_LEN] = { 1.5, -4.8, 2.9, 6.1, 4.2, 1.5, 2.9, 6.1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < VEC_LEN; i++)
    {
        float n = vNums[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < VEC_LEN; j++)
        {
            if (n == vNums[j])
                vFreq[i]++;

            // then my brain freezes
        }
    }
        


    return 0;
}


Aside: Why use float objects with double constants?  More idiomatic in C to use double objects here.

Maybe you want to add a third array like float vCountedNums[VEC_LEN];, and when you first increment vFreq[i] to 1, also set vCountedNums[i] = n;.  That way you'd have a way to "remember" that the count that is present in vFreq[i] corresponds to the floating point value specified in vCountedNums[i]

Are you assured that all the numbers are finite (no infinities, no NaNs), and that you don't have to deal with 0.0 versus -0.0?

@NateEldredge yes

Are you allowed to modify the array?

@Gerhardh Yes, no restrictions on that I guess. Just gotta print each number and their frequencies in each line of output

I'll not give a complete solution in C code. Since you are taking a "computer science course" I think it's best for you to solve it yourself. But here is a description of an algorithm you can implement.
Start by sorting the array vNums. For that you'll use qsort.
After sorting your array will be like:
{ -4.8, 1.5, 1.5, 2.9, 2.9, 4.2, 6.1, 6.1 }

Then you iterate the sorted array and count consecutive equal elements. When two consecutive elements equals increase the counter and move to next element. When two consecutive elements differs, you print the first together with the counter value, and then restart the counting. In pseudo code something like:
count = 1
current_value = sorted_array[0]
index = 1
while index < number_of_element_in_sorted_array
{
    if (current_value == sorted_array[index])
    {
        count = count + 1
    }
    else
    {
        print current_value and count
        count = 1
        current_value = sorted_array[index]
    }
    index = index + 1
}
print current_value and count


@rafamussap the reason for sorting is to speed up the program.
Consider this: if sorted, numbers that are equal are also adjacent in the array so you can scan the sorted array only once. You start counting from the next one until it is different from the previous number, then you record the count and restart with that number.
If the array is not sorted, have to rescan the entire array again and keep track of which numbers you already accounted for.
Try with {1.4, -9.1, 2.0, 1.4, 5.6, 1.4, -9.1}. By the time you see the second 1.4 you need to know that you already accounted for it.

@rafamussap. A general suggestion, if I may. When you try to solve exercises like this, forget your computer. Take pen and paper and draw a sketch to represent the situation (in this case a list of numbers). When you'll become more expert, you'll be able to do it in your mind but trying to solve these problems without a clear picture of what's going on, is very, very difficult (and can be discouraging).
Only after you are sure of WHAT you need to do, you can focus on telling the computer HOW to do it.

As Jeremy mentioned, you need a third array [maybe].

vNums original array with numbers
vMatch contains the value from vNums for the given frequency bucket
vFreq contains the count for the given frequency bucket

Or, using a struct the last two arrays can be combined into one [preferred]

Here is the corrected code for the three array version:
#include <stdio.h>

#define VEC_LEN 8

int
main(void)
{
    int vFreq[VEC_LEN] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    double vMatch[VEC_LEN] = { 0 };
    double vNums[VEC_LEN] = { 1.5, -4.8, 2.9, 6.1, 4.2, 1.5, 2.9, 6.1 };
    int freqcount = 0;
    int freqidx;

    // loop through all values
    for (int i = 0; i < VEC_LEN; i++) {
        // get current value
        double n = vNums[i];

        // look for match to already existing entry in frequency table
        for (freqidx = 0;  freqidx < freqcount;  ++freqidx) {
            if (n == vMatch[freqidx])
                break;
        }

        // no existing match found -- add new entry
        if (freqidx >= freqcount) {
            vMatch[freqidx] = n;
            freqcount += 1;
        }

        // increase the frequency count
        vFreq[freqidx] += 1;
    }

    // print all frequencies
    for (freqidx = 0;  freqidx < freqcount;  ++freqidx)
        printf("Value: %.1f Frequency: %d\n",vMatch[freqidx],vFreq[freqidx]);

    return 0;
}


Here is the output:
Value: 1.5 Frequency: 2
Value: -4.8 Frequency: 1
Value: 2.9 Frequency: 2
Value: 6.1 Frequency: 2
Value: 4.2 Frequency: 1


Here is a version that has two arrays and uses a struct and pointer:
#include <stdio.h>

#define VEC_LEN 8

struct freq {
    double freq_match;
    int freq_count;
};

int
main(void)
{
    struct freq freq_table[VEC_LEN] = { 0 };
    double vNums[VEC_LEN] = { 1.5, -4.8, 2.9, 6.1, 4.2, 1.5, 2.9, 6.1 };
    int freqcount = 0;
    int freqidx;
    struct freq *freq;

    // loop through all values
    for (int i = 0; i < VEC_LEN; i++) {
        // get current value
        double n = vNums[i];

        // look for match to already existing entry in frequency table
        freq = freq_table;
        for (freqidx = 0;  freqidx < freqcount;  ++freqidx, ++freq) {
            if (n == freq->freq_match)
                break;
        }

        // no existing match found -- add new entry
        if (freqidx >= freqcount) {
            freq->freq_match = n;
            freqcount += 1;
        }

        // increase the frequency count
        freq->freq_count += 1;
    }

    // print all frequencies
    freq = freq_table;
    for (freqidx = 0;  freqidx < freqcount;  ++freqidx, ++freq)
        printf("Value: %.1f Frequency: %d\n",freq->freq_match,freq->freq_count);

    return 0;
}


Here is the program output:
Value: 1.5 Frequency: 2
Value: -4.8 Frequency: 1
Value: 2.9 Frequency: 2
Value: 6.1 Frequency: 2
Value: 4.2 Frequency: 1


Here is an advanced version that eliminates freqidx and uses a macro for the for loops:
#include <stdio.h>

#define VEC_LEN 8

struct freq {
    double freq_match;
    int freq_count;
};

#define FREQ_FORALL \
    freq = &freq_table[0];  freq < &freq_table[freqcount];  ++freq

int
main(void)
{
    struct freq freq_table[VEC_LEN] = { 0 };
    double vNums[VEC_LEN] = { 1.5, -4.8, 2.9, 6.1, 4.2, 1.5, 2.9, 6.1 };
    int freqcount = 0;
    struct freq *freq;

    // loop through all values
    for (int i = 0; i < VEC_LEN; i++) {
        // get current value
        double n = vNums[i];

        // look for match to already existing entry in frequency table
        for (FREQ_FORALL) {
            if (n == freq->freq_match)
                break;
        }

        // no existing match found -- add new entry
        if (freq >= &freq_table[freqcount]) {
            freq->freq_match = n;
            freqcount += 1;
        }

        // increase the frequency count
        freq->freq_count += 1;
    }

    // print all frequencies
    for (FREQ_FORALL)
        printf("Value: %.1f Frequency: %d\n",freq->freq_match,freq->freq_count);

    return 0;
}

